# Tagging system with relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i implement a tagging system for our articles.

```
 class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles


end


 class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles


end


class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :region
      belongs_to :country

      def self.tagged_with(name)
        Tag.find_by_name!(name).articles
      end

    end
```

Article controller:

```
def index
    if params[:tag]
       @articles = Article.tagged_with(params[:tag])
      else
        @region = Region.find(params[:region_id])        
        @article_region = @region.articles
      end
  end
```

On my index page i show only the articles which are related with the correct region `params(region_id)`, so this is works fine. But how can i integrate the region and country params in the "tagged_with" functionality?

Example

`/en/italy/umbria/articles/wines` > shows articles tagged with "wines" and which have a relationship with the region umbria

`/en/italy/tuscany/articles/wines` > shows articles tagged with "wines" and which have a relationship with the region tuscany

/en/italy/articles/wines > shows articles tagged with "wines" and which have a relationship with the country italy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: nesting Your resources and using dynamic segments. Check rails guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments

Basically You can say like this:

```
# routes.rb, You should put this just before defining root path. Also test how it works with routes scopes/namespaces
get ':country/:region/articles/:tag', to: "articles#tagged_and_regional"
```

Controller:

```
#articles_controller.rb
def tagged_and_regional
  Article.tagged_and_regional(params[:country], params[:region], params[:tag])
end
```

Model:

```
# I don't know Your data structure, so I am taking a guess
def self.tagged_and_regional(country, region, tag)
  joins(:region, :country, :tags)
    .where("counties.name = ? AND regions.name = ? AND tags.name = ?", country, region, name)
end
```